# How to delete a random edge in networkx?

Tags: networkx

Suppose you have a graph `graph = nx.read_gml("x.gml")` and you'd like to drop `n` edges. Is there any quick way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using the `sample` function from the `random` library. I set `k`, the number of edges to be sampled to 2.

```
import networkx as nx
import random
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,5]])
to_remove=random.sample(G.edges(),k=2)
G.remove_edges_from(to_remove)
print(G.edges())
```